# Depth camera ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

i have iphone 7 plus, and i try to taken image with depth data. 
I use this code for configuration.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/capturing_photos_with_depth

but on

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    
    print(photo.depthData)
}
```

result is nill.
How i can get depthData. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled` to `true` by checking if it is supported.

The device needs a "back-facing dual camera or a front-facing TrueDepth camera"

This is speculation but I think TrueDepth only includes the A11 chip+ and it was introduced with iPhone 8. So, `isDepthDataDeliverySupported` seems to be `false` on iPhone 7.

```
// Set up photo output for depth data capture.
let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliverySupported
guard self.captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput)
   else { fatalError("Can't add photo output.") }
self.captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
self.captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/capturing_photos_with_depth

Comment: iphone 7 plus have 2 cam but isDepthDataDeliverySupported return false.The problem is that I can't find anywhere in the documentation the list of devices that isDepthDataDeliverySupported is true

Comment: @Stefan The only list I have ever seen is the [required capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/support/required-device-capabilities/) list but it does not include a box for this case. All they have is the variable if it is false they don't support it.

Comment: Something else is bothering me. As far as I could find, only the front camera can be true depth (there are additional sensors that accurately determine the distance) as far as I understand the depth of the rear cameras is solved by software.

Comment: @Stefan I agree with your research TrueDepth is only advertised for the FaceID it seems like. Lidar is in the most recent devices for the back cameras but I don't think that applies to this.